# Custom format for logger arguments before merging them to the main logger message

Tags: python, logging

The [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html) module is a neat way to maintain a clean program logger, with customizable things such as message formatting. There is still a point that is not clear to me: how to specify a custom formatting for the arguments (the series of `*args` to be merged into the `msg` format string) passed to the Logger class methods (e.g. `logger.info` or `logger.debug`) *before* they are merged into the `msg` format string?.

For instance, consider the following simple case:

```py
import logging

from termcolor import colored

# regular logging
logging.basicConfig(level="INFO", format="%(levelname)s\t%(message)s")
logging.info("Hello, %s", "world")

# same with explicitely using bold format for the argument
logging.info("Hello, %s", colored("world", attrs=["bold"]))
```

Resulting in the following output:

```
INFO    Hello, world!
INFO    Hello, world!
```

Is there a way to specify once for all the formatting for every additional argument passed to the logger method without manually changing every logging?

Comment: Implement your own [`Formatter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#formatter-objects)?

Answer (score 1):

This [section](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging) has a nice example for using `logging.Formatter()`

```
import logging    
from termcolor import colored

new_format = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s\t' + colored('%(message)s', attrs=['bold']))

handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler.setFormatter(new_format)

logger = logging.getLogger('')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(handler)

logger.info('Hello world!')
```

**EDIT**

Realized this works too

```
import logging
from termcolor import colored

logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s:\t' + colored('%(message)s', attrs=['bold']), level=logging.INFO)
logging.info('Hello World!')
```